# CiviCRM Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails error after upgrading from 4.7.30 to 5.0.2

Tags: upgrade, database

After running the command to upgrade the database I got a constraint violation error.

ERROR USERINFO: ALTER TABLE `civicrm_case` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_case_case_type_id` FOREIGN KEY (`case_type_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_case_type` (`id`) [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails...

I tried adding the foreign key in the database but that did not work. I got this error:  MySQL ERROR 1005: Can’t create table (errno: 150)

The Foreign Key exists on the my live site's db so I imported a db backup from the lives site. Ran the db update command again and got the same error.

How do I prevent the migration from deleting the foreign key?

This is my civicrm_case:

CREATE TABLE `civicrm_case` (

> `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Unique Case ID',
>   `case_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK civicrm_case_type.id',
>   `subject` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Short name of the case.',
>   `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Date on which given case starts.',
>   `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Date on which given case ends.',
>   `details` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT 'Details about the meeting (agenda, notes, etc).',
>   `status_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Id of case status.',
>   `is_deleted` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   KEY `index_case_type_id` (`case_type_id`),
>   KEY `index_is_deleted` (`is_deleted`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=147 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: That doesn't really make sense because there are no updates to that table in upgrading from 4.7.30 to 5.0.2

Comment: have you moved the db (eg by taking a backup and reading in to a new or other db)?

Comment: I imported a back up of the db after the db upgrade failed. I also tried importing the civicrm db from the live site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround to this is to comment out the SQL lines in the file that drop, modify and rebuild the FK.  /CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/4.6.18.mysql.tlp

This will have to be done for every upgrade with a db that does not include the FK.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't really make sense because there are no updates to that table in upgrading from 4.7.30 to 5.0.2

Here is how that table should look

`` CREATE TABLE `civicrm_case` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Unique Case ID',
  `case_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK to civicrm_case_type.id',
  `subject` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Short name of the case.',
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Date on which given case starts.',
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Date on which given case ends.',
  `details` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT 'Details about the meeting (agenda, notes, etc).',
  `status_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Id of case status.',
  `is_deleted` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'When was the case was created.',
  `modified_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'When was the case (or closely related entity) was created or modified or deleted.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_case_type_id` (`case_type_id`),
  KEY `index_is_deleted` (`is_deleted`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_case_case_type_id` FOREIGN KEY (`case_type_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_case_type` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci; ``

What is in civicrm.domain.version?

Comment: The version of Civi is actually 4.7.13